# Computer under domain gives req_timed_out in browser for application

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I've Windows Server2008R2 with ADDS configured. Also the same server got the Java application running in Tomcat.

So, when I open the particular service of that application from the computer which is under domain, it waits for 20-30 minutes then gives no results with err_timeout.

When I run the same thing from the computer which is NOT under domain, it gives back what it should. So, it works fine.

That application's service does a heavy calculation so it takes some time for the job to get done, based on our calculations somewhere around 30 min. But what's buzzing me is, why it works for computers which r not under domain, but it does not when the computer is under domain.

I've run this test in three computers which were not under domain, and it worked fine.

I've tried Opera, IE, Chrome, Firefox. Even changed req_timeout up to 10k, but it didnt help for computers which were under domain. I've to point, I changed the req_timeout for Firefox browser.

Is there any configuration for domain computers, which changes the req_timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Domain security policy can intentionally or unwillingly limit some functionality of such applications.
That is the most probably cause. So you should investigate domain secpol to see if anything is restricted/miss-configured there.

Comment: where exactly in secpool?

Comment: There are a lot of things that must be checked. User rights assignments, security options, app control-->script rules, software restrictions. It's best that you compare the configuration to the local one. Tt's easier to spot when something is miss-configured.

Comment: Well, Ive seen all changes which ive done in Group Policy. There are none actually for security part, and the domain is setted to its default. Nothing is changed. I've changed only the password expire time and blocked the usb for comps. Thats it. So, the secuirty thing doesnt seem like a problem